# How do I partition a hard drive using Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a 300GB hard drive and want to make a seperate partition in Mac OS X? How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(**Update:** As Gordon Davisson said in the comments, make a back up first!)

Open Disk Utility. Select your hard drive in the sidebar. Select the "Partition" tab. Click the "+" button. Resize to your heart's content. Apply. Wait, and try not to do anything.

Comment: I'd add a preliminary step: back up anything important before messing with your partitioning.  I've seen this live repartition process fail in a variety of ways (although -- so far anyway -- never in a way that looses data).

Comment: Always good advice to have backups when fooling around with such things!